# Core Plot : show time in x-axis

Tags: core-plot

I am newbie of Core Plot. I have data of time and temperature data. I am using CPTXYGraph to plot Y-axis (temperature) and X-axis (time in minutes). But I have no idea to show the x-axis in format 01:00, 01:15 etc ?

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is to assign a label formatter for the x-axis to print the time values as you want it. Use something like this:

```
CPTXYAxis *x = axisSet.xAxis;
x.labelTextStyle = textStyle; // a CPTTextStyle you created for color/font etc.

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [NSDateFormatter alloc] initWithDateFormat: @"mm:ss" allowNaturalLanguage: NO];
x.labelFormatter = formatter;
```